# Do actions taken by a future "happen-before" a Future#isDone call that returns true?

Tags: java, synchronization

Suppose I run the following function:

```
boolean functionWithAsyncTask() {
  boolean[] b = new boolean[1];
  b[0] = false;
  Future<?> f = executorService.submit(() -> {
    b[0] = true;
    return null;
  });
  while (!f.isDone()) {
    // ... do some other work with no synchronization ...
  }
  return b[0];
}
```

Is it guaranteed to return `true` (assuming it returns at all), or could it possibly return `false`?

More abstractly, I believe this question is the same as: does `Future#isDone` returning `true` establish a happens-before relationship in which actions taken by the asynchronous thread happen-before code following the call to `isDone`?

Comment: It doesn't even guarantee the future completed. Why not use `get()`?

Comment: Oh, you certainly should use `get()`. I spotted a more subtle incarnation of this construction while debugging a mysterious failure, though, and I was curious if a race could be the culprit. Why do you say it doesn't guarantee the future is completed, though? The function can only return if `f.isDone()` returns `true`, and the docs for `isDone` say it will only return true if the task is completed, so that seems safe.

Comment: The docs also imply `isDone()` can return true while it's still running, if [`cancel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-) fails. So I guess it depends on your definition of "completed".

Comment: Maybe ... I would read the docs to mean that `isDone()` wouldn't return `true` if `cancel()` was called but failed. In any event, though, there's no cancellation going on in the program I'm looking at.

Comment: Could it be throwing an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are really two questions, so I'll answer them separately:

> Is it guaranteed to return `true`

No. Only `Future.get()` has a documented *happens-before* guarantee. Furthermore, such a guarantee couldn't exist because `isDone()` will return true if a task is cancelled or throws an exception.

> could it possibly return `false`?

Not if it completes normally. In the standard `FutureTask` implementation, `isDone()` checks the volatile field `state`, which is normally set after the task completes, creating a *happens-before* edge.